# Which directory should I install the official PHP mongodb driver in?

Tags: php, mongodb, installation

I found the official driver here:

```
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver
```

My problem is: I don't know which location should I be in to start the install process?
I am on Mac OS X Snow Leopard and have both Mamp and Mamp pro on my machine.

Could someone please help me install this php mongodb driver?

Comment: see http://us.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.osx

Comment: I tried that Paul. The manual mentions XAMPP for some reason. That's for windows - not OS x :(

Comment: Sorry, I was reading "Extract mongo.so from the archive and add it to MAMP or XAMPP's extension directory" which after a quick Googling looks like something along the lines of `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/`. Disclaimer: I'm not using OS X or MAMP.

Comment: Another way to find the extensions directory is to create a page from [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) or if you have the cli installed: `php -i | grep extension_dir`

Answer (score 1):

The general case should be solved by running PHP, and seeing where it is actually looking for the extensions:

```
# php -i | grep extension_dir
```

On my (linux) server, this returns the line:

```
extension_dir => /usr/lib/php5/20090626 => /usr/lib/php5/20090626
```

The usual method of installing any such module is with Pecl - eg, `pecl install mongo`. Having to manually move it into place probably means there's something else wrong first.

Comment: I get `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626 => /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626`

should I install it here?

Comment: Yep. Take a look, there may well already be some extensions in there. It will be a subset of the list of modules from `php -m` (many of them will be built-in to the php executable already)

Answer (score 1):

Just like any other extension, it should be installed with "pecl install mongo". That will download and compile and install the driver in the correct directory for you. All you then need to do is add an "extension=mongo.so" in your php.ini.

Comment: so should I start with installing pear and then pecl?

Comment: Yes, pear should however be installed by default though. I wonder why MAMP doesn't have it! You might just find it in a different path. Try searching for it.

Comment: I can see a pear directory but when I do pear version on the command line, I get nada